# eeePC brightness doesn't switch from AC to battery mode

Tags: display

on my eeePC, when I set up a brightness value on battery mode, it affects also AC mode and vice-versa.

Is there a solution to this issue?.

Thanks for the answer

Comment: The *On Battery* and *Plugged In* buttons on the settings dialog only apply to the options underneath them.